# Javascript closures -- what is the difference between these

Tags: javascript, closures

**EDIT**

With the number of responses saying "you can make private things!" below, I'm going to add this to the top as well:

*I know you can emulate private variables within a closure.  That is not what I'm asking.  I'm asking, given the two examples below where I'm "exporting" EVERYTHING from the closure, what is the fundamental difference between these two examples.*

Given these two methods of creating objects/methods:

```
var test = {}

test = (function(){
    var a_method = function(print_me){
        return "hello "+print_me;
    }

    return {print_me: a_method};
})();

test.print_me2 = function(print_me2){
   return "hello "+print_me2;
}

test.print_me('world');
>>> returns "hello world"

test.print_me2('world');
>>> returns "hello world"
```

I understand that the first method allows for private variables (which as a python developer at heart i don't really care to use), but both seem rather equivilent to me, only the first one looks "cooler" (as in all the big javascript people seem to be doing it that way) and the second way looks very passé.

So, like, what is the difference?

I've looked through the closure questions here -- most of them center around what or why do you use them; I understand their utility, I just want to know why you'd do the first over the second and what benefits it has.

I'd prefer hard evidence over conjecture -- not looking for a "this is how the cool kids are doing it" or "i heard that mozilla does better memory usage when you use a closure", but rather qualitative evidence towards one being 'better' than the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the methods is the anonymous function wrapper that creates a closure, but also that the first method replaces the entire object while the second method just sets a property in the existing method.

There are different ways of adding methods to an object. You can put them there when you create the object:

```
var test = {
  print_me: function(text) { return "hello " + text; }
};
```

You can add a method as a property to an existing object:

```
var test = {};
test.print_me = function(text) { return "hello " + text; };
```

You can make a constructor function, and add methods to its prototype:

```
function Test() {}
Test.prototype.print_me = function(text) { return "hello " + text; };
var test = new Test();
```

As Javascript has a prototype based object model, the last one is how methods were intended to be created. The other ways are just possible because an object property can have a function as value.

---

You can use a function wrapper around any code where you want local variables, so you can do that with the second way of setting the property:

```
test.print_me2 = (function(){

  var method = function(print_me2) {
    return "hello "+print_me2;
  }

  return method;
})();
```

Comment: that's a much better answer than before.  And yes, I understand I'm setting the object to be the result of the immediately executed function rather than setting a property of said object -- lets assume i'm trying to make just `print_me` which will be the only property on the test object.  What would be the benefits of doing it in a closure rather than doing it as a straight assignment?

Comment: @tkone: The benefit of doing it in a closure is just that you have the closure. You can create local variables, so that you don't pollute the global namespace. However, being careful with the global namespace is more of an issue if you are writing library code or plugins. The big library jQuery for example only adds two names to the global namespace.

Comment: ok cool.  that's exactly what I was trying to figure out.m  I know adding a ton of names to the global namespace is a bad idea (hence using namespacing), but just wanted to know if people were doing closures because they're "hot" or if they served a utility in a case like above.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, the closure is used to keep local variables out of the global scope.

```
var thisIsGlobal = 2;
var test = (function () {
  var thisIsLocal = 3;
  return function () {
    return thisIsLocal;
  };
}());
```

What you get is a function `test` which when invoked returns the value of the local variable `thisIsLocal`. There is no way to change the value of the variable. You can be look at it as to a private variable.

Comment: "no way" is not entirely correct. Some (old'ish) js engines allow to access the `.__parent__` attribute of functions, which infact would allow to access a closured parent scope.

Comment: @JanKuča I understand the scoping issues here -- what I'm asking has nothing to do with private/public or emulation thereof, but rather the difference between the two examples -- one in a closure exporting EVERYTHING and one outside of a closure.

Comment: I don't think there is any actual difference between the two. You should use the latter. The self-executing anonymous wrapper doesn't provide any added value.

Answer (score 0):

The first method you present (an anonymous function which is executed immediately) keeps your program out of the global scope. Within that private scope you can decide what properties you want to expose as your API:

```
(function(win){
  var a, b, c = 1;  

  function init(){ 
    return aa(b);
  }

  function exit(){
    if(cc()){
      return a;
    }
  }

  function aa(){
  }

  function bb(){
  }

  function cc(){
  }

  win.myProgram = {init: init,
                   exit: exit };
})(window);


// We now have access to your API from within the global namespace:    
myProgram.init();    
//etc
```